# React component not rerendring when state is changed with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My state is changing as I can see in console but my Book component is not refreshed on state change. I have two containers/components in my app. BookList that renders the list of all available books. Book component just gets the activeBook and display its details. I am facing the rerender issue on Book Component.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Book extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-md-9 details">
                <h3>Title: {this.props.activeBook.name}</h3>
                <p><b>Author:</b> {this.props.activeBook.author}</p>
                <p><b>Pages:</b>{this.props.activeBook.pages}</p>
                <p><b>Available:</b>{this.props.activeBook.aval}</p>
                {console.log(this.props)}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        activeBook: state.active
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Book);
```

My BookList Component is as following

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class BookList extends Component{

    renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map((book)=>{
            return(
                <li 
                    key={book.id} 
                    onClick={() => this.props.dispatch({type:'CHANGED',activeBook:book})}
                    className="list-group-item">
                    {book.name}
                </li>
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-md-3">
                <ul className='list-group'>
                    {this.renderList()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        books:state.books
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

My App.js is as follows:-

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


//Import All Components Here
import BookList from './containers/BookList';
import Book from './components/Book';

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="App">
          <div className="row">
            <BookList/>
            <Book/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and lastly my bookReducer is as follows:-

```js
const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        case 'CHANGED':
            state.active=action.activeBook;
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }

}

export default bookReducer;
```

I can exactly see in my console that State is being changed, but problem is Book Container does not respond to that change. In index.js this is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import bookReducer from './reducers/bookReducer';

const initialState={
    books:[
      {id:1,name:'Learn Java', author:'Shakeel', pages:50,aval:'Yes'},
      {id:2,name:'React Native', author:'Asim', pages:212,aval:'No'},
      {id:3,name:'Angular JS', author:'Tahir', pages:150,aval:'Yes'},
      {id:4,name:'NodeJS', author:'Saleem', pages:120,aval:'Yes'},
      {id:5,name:'C++ for Games', author:'Shakeel', pages:140,aval:'Yes'}
    ],
    active:{id:5,name:'C++ for Games', author:'Shakeel', pages:140,aval:'Yes'}
  };

const store = createStore(bookReducer,initialState);




ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App /></Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think it should be `<h3>\`Title: ${this.props.activeBook.name}\`</h3>`?

Comment: What’s the issue are you facing? Please include these details in question also include booklist component code

Comment: @Marson Mao that doesn’t matter, what OP has is correct

Comment: This code seems to be correct, how many reducers do you have ? do you use combinereducers ?

Comment: @HemadriDasari here is my BookList

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G I am not using combineReducers as I've only 1 reducer in my app.

Comment: Share the reducer file as well. Share the relevant code at once please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are setting the state in reducer needs to change, try this change.

```
const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {

switch(action.type){
    case 'CHANGED':

        return {
           ...state,
           active : action.activeBook
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: But state is already changing boss, I can see that in React Dev tools

Comment: That worked by I could not understand what was issue in previous approach. As I was seeing active book was changing there.

Comment: It expects a object to be returned, you where returning a state which was a array initially

Comment: Okay, you have been so quick on this. Stay Blessed